# How to make Firefox stop prompting for the Primary Password

Tags: firefox, passwords

Every time I open Firefox, it pops up a prompt to enter my Primary Password:
[image: Password Required - Mozilla Firefox / Please enter your Primary Password. / Cancel & Sign in buttons]

There's no need to sign in until I actually want it to autofill a password, so is there a way to stop this appearing on startup and only appear when I go to a website with a password field?

Comment: This is likely due to some add-on trying to open a password-protected page. Start in Troubleshoot Mode (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/diagnose-firefox-issues-using-troubleshoot-mode), and if there is no password prompt, check add-ons one at a time.

Comment: The prompt still appears in Troubleshoot Mode.